# Create pie chart using values of 3 integers

Tags: c#, .net, pie-chart

I'm trying to create a piechart using data i get from my struct pie. In this struct i have 3 counters (r_count, i_count, j_count) and a total number (total_count). I used the code above but the form that comes up is empty. Any idea or solution?

```
float p1 = pie.r_count / pie.total_instr;
float p2 = pie.i_count / pie.total_instr;
float p3 = pie.j_count / pie.total_instr;

Graphics graphics = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 150, 150);

Brush b1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
Brush b2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
Brush b3 = new SolidBrush(Color.Maroon);

Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);

graphics.Clear(Form1.DefaultBackColor);
graphics.DrawPie(p, rect, 0, p1);
graphics.FillPie(b1, rect, 0, p1);
graphics.DrawPie(p, rect, p1, p2);
graphics.FillPie(b2, rect, p1, p2);
graphics.DrawPie(p, rect, p2 + p1, p3);
graphics.FillPie(b3, rect, p2 + p1, p3);
```

Comment: Use breakpoints, single step through your code. What are the values for `p1`, `p2` and `p3`?

Comment: p1 = 0.2, p2 = 0.6, p3 = 0.2

Comment: Did you read this values from the debugger or just calculated on paper?

Comment: I read them using Step Into Debugging and had a breakpoint where the values were calculated

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast one of the two `integers` to a `float`:

```
float p1 = (float)pie.r_count / pie.total_instr;
```

or

```
float p1 = pie.r_count / (float)pie.total_instr;
```

Otherwise the result would be always 0. Why?

When we divide two integers, let's say `a` and `b`, then the result would be 0, if `a<b`.

As you understand, you have to make the same changes for `p2` and `p3`.

**Update**

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk641104%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), we see that the signature of `DrawPie` method is the following:

```
public void DrawPie(
    Pen pen,
    RectangleF rect,
    float startAngle,
    float sweepAngle
)
```

where `startAngle` is an angle measured in degrees clockwise from the x-axis to the first side of the pie shape and `endAngle` is an angle measured in degrees clockwise *from the startAngle parameter to the second side of the pie shape*.

That being said, you have to make the following change:

```
float p1 = ((float)pie.r_count / pie.total_instr)*360;
float p2 = ((float)pie.i_count / pie.total_instr)*360;
float p3 = ((float)pie.j_count / pie.total_instr)*360;
```

Comment: I tried  your (@DrKoch, Christos) solution but nothing changed. Form still shows up empty

Comment: @Christos I guess you meant `(float)` instead of `(cast)`

Comment: @DrKoch I mean to cast the `integer` to a `float`. In other words to convert the integer to a float.

Comment: Of course, but your code-snippet says (cast) (just a typo...)

Comment: @StavrosAfxentis may I ask you something? Could you please point a break point next to `p1` and when the execution reach this point, before you enter F10 - this will execute the assignment- to tell us what are the value of `pie.r_count` and `pie.total_instr`. Then hit F10 and tells us what is the value of `p1`.  Thanks.

Comment: @StavrosAfxentis if something in my previous comment doesn't make sense, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @DrKoch no problem at all with your comment dude. :) Thank you very much ! Good catch !

Comment: @christos I took the freedom to edit your second code snippet again. makes more sense that way ;)

Comment: r_count = 1 
i_count = 3
j_count = 1
total_instr = 5

Comment: @StavrosAfxentis ok great. It is something that I expected. If you know make the cast I refer to my answer you will get for `p1`, `p2` and `p3` the values `0.2`, `0.6` and `0.2` correspondingly. You could verify this with the same way -debugging-. If this happens and you still not see the chart, then we should look in another place for the error. So, please verify me that these are the values we get. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i finally managed to find a solution to this problem. The code is shown below:

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public chart pie;
    Graphics graphics;

    public float d1;
    public float d2;
    public float d3;

    public Form3(chart ch)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pie = ch;
        graphics = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
    }

    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       d1 = 360 * (((float)pie.r_count)/((float)pie.total_instr));
       d2 = 360 * (((float)pie.i_count) / ((float)pie.total_instr));
       d3 = 360 * (((float)pie.j_count) / ((float)pie.total_instr));
       //comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SolidBrush b1 = new SolidBrush (Color.Blue);
        SolidBrush b2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        SolidBrush b3 = new SolidBrush(Color.LawnGreen);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(60,10,200,200);
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);

        graphics.DrawPie(p, rect, 0, d1);
        graphics.FillPie(b1, rect, 0, d1);
        graphics.DrawPie(p, rect, d1, d2);
        graphics.FillPie(b2, rect, d1, d2);
        graphics.DrawPie(p, rect, d1 + d2, d3);
        graphics.FillPie(b3, rect, d1+d2, d3);
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

            label1.Text = "R_type   (" + (d1 * 100 / 360).ToString() + "%)";
            label2.Text = "I_type   (" + (d2 * 100 / 360).ToString() + "%)";
            label3.Text = "J_type   (" + (d3 * 100 / 360).ToString() + "%)";
            label5.Enabled = false;




    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            label1.Text = "R_type   (" + (d1 * 100 / 360).ToString() + "%)";
            label2.Text = "I_type   (" + (d2 * 100 / 360).ToString() + "%)";
            label3.Text = "J_type   (" + (d3 * 100 / 360).ToString() + "%)";
            label5.Enabled = false;

        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "R_type   (" + (pie.r_count).ToString() + ")";
            label2.Text = "I_type   (" + (pie.i_count).ToString() + ")";
            label3.Text = "J_type   (" + (pie.j_count).ToString() + ")";
            label5.Text += "Total Instructions = " + pie.total_instr.ToString();
            label5.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

And the result is shown below! Thanks everyone for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if `pie.total_instr` is an `int` you need this:

```
float p1 = pie.r_count / (float)pie.total_instr;
```

to avoid an integer division which is always 0 in your cases

Answer (score 0):

Multiply p1,p2,p3 by 360 before drawing, the [DrawPie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk641104%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function takes degrees

```
float p1 = pie.r_count * 360 / pie.total_instr;
float p2 = pie.i_count * 360 / pie.total_instr;
float p3 = pie.j_count * 360 / pie.total_instr;
```

Comment: Did that but still nothing.. I dont know what else to do!

Comment: should be `360.0` to avoid integer division